# Increase counter on keypress angular 4 and decrease on backspace

Tags: html, angular

I am new angular and What im trying to achieve is.

- When we enter some text in textarea the character in the label will increase
- When we press backspace the counter should decrease.
- If user tries to enter more than the specified character the counter should display 0, and user should not be able to type anything
- If they press backspace, it should display the no of characters in the text area

In my HTML I have:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 nopadding">
  <mat-form-field class="col-sm-12 nopadding">
    <textarea 
      matInput 
      placeholder="Role" 
      (keydown)="CounterMax(800,$event)" 
      [(ngModel)]="txtRole" 
      aria-label="Role">
    </textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
  <label class="nopadding clrlbl">
    Minimum character: {{lblRole}}
  </label>
  <br/>
</div>
```

In my ts file i have this function

```
lblRole: number = 800;
CounterMax(count, event) {
  var data = event.target.value.length;
  if (data >= count) {
    this.lblRole = 0;
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Somehow, i manage to increase the counter and prevent user from entering once the no. of characters is more than 800, but i don't know how to handle backspace press and decrease the counter.
Can you please help me with this.

Comment: Check for `if($event.keyCode == 8) count--;`

Comment: angular has built in validators , please use built-in-validators : https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#built-in-validators

Comment: if it's only for validation goals why you're not using MaxLengthValidator of angular

Comment: @FatehMohamed  Sorry i am not aware of that, will read about it and implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't really get the rationale behind this requirement:

> If user tries to enter more than the specified character the counter should display 0, and user should not be able to type anything

I think a better UX would be to show the user `{{role.length}}/{{maxChars}}`

But apart from that, everything can be achieved simply by using `[maxlength]` as Property Binding Syntax.

Try this:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 nopadding">
  <textarea 
    placeholder="Role"
    [(ngModel)]="role"
    [maxlength]="maxChars">
  </textarea>
  <br/>
  <br>
  <label class="nopadding clrlbl">
    Characters Remaining: {{role.length}}/{{maxChars}}
  </label>
  <br/>
</div>
```

And in your Class:

```
@Component({...})
export class AppComponent  {
  maxChars = 800;
  role = '';
  chars = 0;
}
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-text-area-with-length?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: It worked, ill try to make changes according to my requirement, will let u know in case of any doubts